# How do I get rid of this odd dual view in XCode?

Tags: xcode

There was a run time exception in my iPhone application in Xcode, and this panel appeared that was divided in two.

The left side seems to be my code, while the right side is marking where code is inserted. What is going on, and how do I get rid of this dual view?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's weird. It looks like your system crashed and wound up in the middle of a diff viewer. Usually executing random code doesn't do anything functional, but random is random so it's possible to get a (seemingly) useful output.

In any case, since something threw the run-time exception you can assume the system isn't in a stable state. I would reboot.

Comment: Yeah rebooting worked. Sorry, late response.